# Default gateway objective c code integration issue in swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have implemented the code available in the below link to get the WiFi gateway address.

[How to get the WIFI gateway address on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872196/how-to-get-the-wifi-gateway-address-on-the-iphone)

When I am trying to access the method (written in Objective C) which returns the gateway address, from the Swift class, it shows the following error.
"Use of undeclared type 'DummyClass' "

The swift code snippet where I am getting error is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var instanceOfCustomObject: dummyClass = dummyClass()   //While initialising instanceOfCustomObject, the above said error comes.
```

PS: Bridging header for integration of Objective-C code with Swift code also has been added.

Any help to resolve the above issue is highly appreciated.Thank You!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Does it say undeclared type 'DummyClass'` or 'dummyClass'?  Code and error message would never be seen together.  And is your class declaration properly using upper case character or lower case character.