# Any one Know ?? how to get router ip address from mac and iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

i wanna get router ip address,i got code for how to get ip address but i didn't get router ip address(Ex: 20.30.40.01 like that).any one know please ping me..

Comment: Are you looking for the router's internal IP address (the LAN address and your device's gateway), or the external IP address (the WAN address)?

Comment: http://imgur.com/WvD44Af

Comment: see about image i wanna that router address...

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like using the user's IP address for an iOS app *may* be against Apple's terms. If not you may have to ask permission first

Comment: Also, your question will most likely be closed if you don't edit in more. So, what have you tried and why doesn't it work? What *exactly* are you looking for?

Comment: is it possible to convert ip address to router address??becz end of should be 1 that is router address

Comment: see the image i wanna that router ip address: http://imgur.com/WvD44Af

Comment: programmatically i can do as a ip address programmatically but i can't get router ip address programmatically

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your local network router is always at 192.168.1.1 it plays the role of "machine 1" on the local network, or the last 1 in 192.168.1."1"

In the event this is not typically default, and to program it into your application I would refer to the code in this posting: ([How can I determine the default gateway on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300149/how-can-i-determine-the-default-gateway-on-iphone))

open up terminal, type:

1. scutil
2. list (Lists all your settings)
3. show State:/Network/Global/DNS
4. Terminal should read "192.168.1.1" or other primary connection(router ip)
5. Should be able to script that and include it into your apps. :)

Happy Coding Ahead!

Comment: yeah thats right but how could i get programmatically

Comment: That might be true for home routers in default configuration but there are networks where the router is not the first host in a subnet.

Comment: ok but i wanna router ip address i got ip address but i can't router ip

Comment: see the image i wanna that router ip address: http://imgur.com/WvD44Af

Comment: could u say what is this #include "getgateway.h" becz while using in the Xcode it showing error

Answer (score 0):

If you want the external address:

```
curl -4 ifconfig.co
curl -6 ifconfig.co
```

If you want the internal address:

Check if your code also returns the `gateway`, that's the routers internal address

Comment: i waana programmatically how to do??

Comment: could u say how to get DHCP Gateway address??

Comment: see the image i wanna that router ip address: http://imgur.com/WvD44Af

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:-
1)Go to Settings
2)Network
3)Advanced
4)Select TCP/IP tab
You will get IP address of MAC.

Comment: bro,could u say programmatically i wanna programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072989/iphone-ipad-osx-how-to-get-my-ip-address-programmatically refer this link

Comment: see the image i wanna that router ip address: http://imgur.com/WvD44Af

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html refer this link

Comment: thats showed mac ip address but i wanna that like 20.30.40.1 like router address