# swift Cannot convert value of type 'in_addr_t' (aka 'UInt32') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<in_addr_t>!'

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I tried to add function from objective c to swift just like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440193/7395969 and I converted call method to Swift as shown below. But I get error : **Cannot convert value of type 'in_addr_t' (aka 'UInt32') to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer!'** on this line : **let r: Int**

```
func getGatewayIP() -> String {
    var ipString: String? = nil

    let gatewayaddr: in_addr
    let r: Int = getdefaultgateway((gatewayaddr.s_addr))
    if r >= 0 {
        ipString = "\(inet_ntoa(gatewayaddr))"
        print("default gateway : \(ipString)")
    }
    else {
        print("getdefaultgateway() failed")
    }
    return ipString!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the *address* of `gatewayaddr.s_addr` as inout argument
with `&`. Also the `gatewayaddr` must be initialized:

```
var gatewayaddr = in_addr()
let r = getdefaultgateway(&gatewayaddr.s_addr)
```

Note that string interpolation

```
    ipString = "\(inet_ntoa(gatewayaddr))"
```

will not work to convert the C string to a Swift `String`,
you have to call `String(cString:)`. Also

```
return ipString!
```

will crash if the gateway could not be determined.

Example of a safe version:

```
func getGatewayIP() -> String? {
    var gatewayaddr = in_addr()
    let r = getdefaultgateway(&gatewayaddr.s_addr)
    if r >= 0 {
        return String(cString: inet_ntoa(gatewayaddr))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

if let gateway = getGatewayIP() {
    print("default gateway", gateway)
} else {
    print("getGatewayIP() failed")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now error is gone, but I get value like this Optional(0x00000001af342ca0), how should I convert to normal gateway ip addresss?

Comment: Thank you mate, working perfect, it is completely what I was looking for few days!!!

Comment: @EgleMatutyte: Here is a pure Swift version of the C function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44745474/1187415.